# To integrate nuance dragon in a .net web application

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, speech-to-text, nuance

I am looking to integrate a speech to text functionality within a WEB application where the users would dictate instead of typing medical notes and the application would capture and save that. Wanted to check if nuance dragon could be integrated within my application to capture and translate voice and return corresponding text which was spoken, which then in turn I could store in my database?

If there are any other alternatives to nuance dragon, would be great to know about those too.

Thanks!

Comment: A quick web-search gave me that: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

Comment: Thanks. But even Google seems to be not accurate enough for healthcare terminologies. Any other recommendations on the healthcare side?